# Sqlite in-memory configuration on databases.yml

Tags: sqlite, symfony1, doctrine

For speeding up functional tests performance, some people suggest to use a sqlite database on the testing environment. I've tried to figure out how to do it but without luck. Here is the configuration which I'm using for the testing environment:

```
(config/databases.yml)
test:
  doctrine:
    class:    sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:    mysql://user:pass@localhost/database_test
```

I would like to replace mysql by sqlite:in-memory.

Comment: Are you referring to this article about [writing efficient tests](http://webmozarts.com/2010/03/11/writing-efficient-tests/) ? What did not work when you tried the replacement?

Comment: Yes! In the referred article, the doctrine dsn configuration is made in bootstrap/unit.php file. I would like to know, if is possible to do the exact same configuration in the config/databases.yml configuration file.

Comment: I think yes. Why didn't you ask my second question?

Comment: I didn't tried the replacement in the bootstrap/unit.php configuration file. I would like to apply the exact same configuration in the config/databases.yml but I do quite understand how to such thing.

Comment: the link tells you the dsn you should use for sqlite in memory databases. Just replace the old value with this one.